# Custom Domain Redirect to a Path/Page in a Community

Tags: community, redirect, napili, custom-domain, custom-url

I have a custom domain, `community.example.com`, set up for a napili-based Community, `example.force.com/community/s/`.

I'd like add new custom domains for the same community but redirect them to a specific page. For example,

- `support.example.com` to `community.example.com/s/support`
- `conference.example.com` to `community.example.com/s/conference`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I want to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible what you want using custom urls

But, you can set up page variations of your home or landing page so that users matching a criteria can see certain home page.

you can read more about page variations here: 
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_networks_builder_profile_access.htm